# How to update UI when data changes in data-binding android?

Tags: android, data-binding

I have an activity that shows one text-view in that:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="Users"
            type="com.example.mvvm.model.UserInfoModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:text="@{Users.name,default = hello}"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And my UserInfoModel class:

```
public class UserInfoModel {
private String name;

public UserInfoModel() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

And in my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityMainBinding binding;
UserInfoModel users;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    
    textView = binding.tvMain;

    users = new UserInfoModel();

    users.setName("Stack");

    viewAction();

    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    binding.setUsers(users);
}
}
```

My Problem is, When I Change **name** in **viewAction** method like this:

```
 private void viewAction() {
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            users.setName("Change Text");
        }
    });
}
```

My UI doesn't change and text-view still showing **Stack**. I try to use `binding.notifyPropertyChanged(id)` but it doesn't affect. Where is my mistake? How can I change the data?

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Did you try to call setUsers again after model was changed?

Comment: @JohnyDeph Is it necessary? Shouldn't it change lives?

Comment: It'll change only if u will use answer below. Or u need to use my approach. In addition, better to use live data in viewmodel pattern to dinamically update ui))

Comment: Actually I don't like solution below, because your model become dirtier

Comment: @JohnyDeph Can are you show me a sample, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make your fields observable in the models.

```
public class UserInfoModel {
private ObservableField<String> name;

public UserInfoModel() {
 this.name = new ObservableField<>();
}

public ObservableField<String> getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name.set(name);
}
}
```

Comment: If I need several parameters like name, family, job, phone, etc... I should define `ObservableField<String>` for them one by one?

Comment: Yes instead of using string just use ObservableField. This is how the library know the fields to observe when the values are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that generated binding class doesn't know when property is changed. You should notify it. First, your viewmodel can be inherited from BaseObservable class, then you have to add @Bindable annotation to getters in your viewmodel and call  notifyPropertyChanged inside  setters with appropriate id from BR class(it's going to be generated for you by databinding library, just add @Bindable annotation. for instance notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name) ). Also you should pay attention how you store "binding" variable in MainActivity class.It can lead to memory leaks. You can investigate that issue. See library like databindingPropertyDelegate.

Something like this

```
public class UserInfoModel extends BaseObservable{
     @Bindable
     public String getName() {
           return name; 
     } 
     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name; 
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
     }
}
```

Comment: I did not think there was a need for `notifyPropertyChanged`. I thought the activity UI would change as the data changed. But, If I use kotlin, how to call `notifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: This method you will inherit from BaseObservable class. Also you can use ObservableField as @Bilal Aslam mentioned, or even Livedate to notify binding class about property changed. Actually, see my example. it does exactly what you expect.

Comment: In kotlin it will the same. Getter must be annotated like this: @get:Bindable (as I remember) and setter should invoke notifypropertyChanged